# Deep linking with Facebook

Tags: facebook, deep-linking

In my iphone application , i have a reqiurement post to facebook.When i click the same post from Facebook the host app should come up.When i searched here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios it requires some metadata to be added in my file. So i did it.

```
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="schemename://" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="app store id" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Example App" />
<!-- Other headers -->
```

But it neither opening my app nor redirecting to itunes.
Please suggest me what i did wrong here??

Comment: Use the debug tool to update the meta data cache, and to verify that there are no errors. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Inferred Property
The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
the app ID in this App Link has a typo
the app hasn’t been published in their store yet
the app is only available in a country that may not be supported by Platform....
Im getting these error
But I already published this app to appstore .

Comment: ok . I cleared all errors rported by debugger tool.Still its not redirecting to my app

Comment: http://purposecodes.com/purposetest/applinks.html
This is the url which i used to debug

Comment: Have you made a new post on Facebook after making these changes, or at least refreshed the existing one?

Comment: Yes, i created a new post.When i click on the post , it directs to facebook browser and stays there.When i check the scheme (purposecolorapp://) in safari, its opening my app.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another work around to this. I discovered it by reverse engineering how Spotify manages deep linking. To see this - share a Spotify playlist on your feed. The Facebook iOS app will launch directly into the Spotify iOS app from the shared playlist.

Long story short - Facebook have enable this for Spotify. If you put this meta tag in:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="174829003346">
```

then your deep links will magically work (that's the Spotify facebook app ID). I'm still trying to establish if this is due to a misconfigured app or if we're looking at a potential anti-trust case.

By the way - this isn't a workable solution. If your app (and thus URL scheme) isn't installed, the Spotify app will open in its place. It is, however, very interesting behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

## This is expected behavior in 2017.

The `al:ios:url` tag you are using *is supposed to do this.* Unfortunately, the functionality has been broken for over a year on iOS, and it is a [known issue](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1640178609532119/) that Facebook has essentially written off as `wontfix`.

Facebook will now only deep link on iOS if `al:web:should_fallback` is set to `false`. This means if your app is not installed, the user will **always** be taken to the App Store page rather than your own website, even if you have specified `al:web:url`. Most savvy brands do not want a new user’s first experience to be the App or Play Store page and they are also not willing to sacrifice attribution data. Because of this, `al:web:should_fallback` is now almost universally set to `false`, which means there is currently no workable way to launch a third-party app directly from the newsfeed in the iOS Facebook app.

Things still work correctly in the Android Facebook app, but obviously this could change at any time. It's unfortunate Facebook hasn't been more transparent about the change to the iOS version, because there is quite a bit of confusion about it.

You can read more about details behind this issue [here](https://blog.branch.io/deep-linking-from-facebook-in-2017/).

### But there is a workaround.

Services like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I am on the team) get around this by implementing a judicious combination of App Links, URI schemes, and iOS Universal Links. Essentially what you need to do is open a page in the webview and then have a button or other user-driven CTA event that launches the app from there. It's an extra step for the user, but currently the best workaround. If you just want to be able to post a link that goes into your app when it is installed and otherwise goes to a webpage (or the App/Play Store), then Branch links are definitely your simplest solution.

*Branch link routing logic*

[image: Branch link routing logic]